# Change the text in a TextBox with Text = "{Binding SomeText}" so it is undoable

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, undo

I have a textbox that has text bound:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" Text="{Binding SomeText}" />
```

Is there a way to change the text from code in a way so that it is undoable.

Only way I can think of is ClipBoard and textBox.Paste() but don't want to alter clipboard in case user has something there.

It is for a control that looks like this:
[image]

The buttons changes the text and I want it to be undoable.

Comment: Nobody wants to sift through your entire project.  Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have no code for it, hence this question. Provided link in case someone is interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TextboxButton.theControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox"/>
    <Button Content="Push me to set textbox text" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

in the code-behind:

```
public partial class theControl : UserControl
{
    public theControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string TextToSet
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextToSetProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextToSetProperty, value); }
    }
    public static DependencyProperty TextToSetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextToSet", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), null);

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox.SelectAll();
        textBox.SelectedText = TextToSet;
    }
}
```

When using it, set the TextToSet property to whatever the button click should provide.

Comment: How is it different from  textBox.Text = "new text";`?

Comment: It's not - you stated that it didn't work in your project, but I am demonstrating that it is a feasible solution.

Comment: If you'd like help identifying why your attempt didn't work properly, post the code of what you tried

Comment: Ok, fair enough, I have something else that is broken. You are right.

Comment: Turns out the problem is that Text is bound. Try binding the text in your sample and you have a repro.

Comment: My question is poor, I will edit it. +1 for your effort.

Comment: I can bind the Text property of my control just fine - and it works as I expected.  Clicking the button sets the text (and the property of my VM) and editing the box directly updates the VM when the control loses focus.  Thanks for the pts.

Comment: Try click button then try to undo the change in the textbox.

Comment: ahhh, I see it now - seems like an oversight of the framework design.  A slightly hacky solution would be to cache the contents of the textbox when the button is clicked, and then handle the ctrl-z gesture.  It would only work for a single undo though...

Comment: whew - finally got it.  See the edits, just select all the ext and then set the selection instead of using setting the text directly.

Comment: Nice, dunno if it has any negative side effects but it works. Ty sir!

Answer (score 0):

When subclassing this is cleaner:

```
this.BeginChange();
this.SetCurrentValue(TextProperty, text);
this.EndChange();
```